I'm trying to type when it gives me the sudo password pop-up
When it gives me the >>[sudo] password for nexboy
popup, I try to type the password, but it says try again later, and it doesn't let me type at all. I even tried looking through old forum posts, and I found one saying the default password is password. So can you please help me find out why I can't type during the password popup.

Are you asking why Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password?

Does the output really say "try again later" or only "try again"? The latter is the standard when entering a wrong password.
Except this, Ubuntu doesn't come with a default password, the password is like you set during the installation.

The password for sudo is the same password you used to login. It's NOT "password".

are you asking about a site on the internet or your own PC or device that is running the Ubuntu you install?

This question is similar to: Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
